# SED: combining select fields from multiple lines into one line

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk

I have files in the form:

```
random stuff  
more random stuff, etc  
more random stuff, etc   
05201206 field1 field2 field3 field4 field5  
05201212 field1 field2 field3 field4 field5  
05201218 field1 field2 field3 field4 field5
```

where the fields are lats and lons

What I want to do is find all the lines that begin with "05" and take fields 1, 3 - from each and then print the results all onto one single line in the order found, such as: (trying to write KML code)

```
field1, field3, 0 field1, field3, 0 field1, field3, 0  field1, field3, 0
```

Also, related question - can math be done in sed? Ideally, each of the lats and lons should be divided by 10.0 before printing the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do math in `sed`. `awk` is the right tool for tokenzing and processing the fields.

```
awk '/^05/{ $4/=10.0;$2/=10.0;out=out$2","$4","}END{print out }' inputFile
```

Comment: Agreed -- `awk` is the appropriate command here. [Here's a tutorial.](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is clearly the right tool for the job, but you can certainly use `sed` for a portion of the task.  Filters are a powerful idea:

```
<input sed -n /^05/p                    | # print only lines starting "05" 
  awk '{print 0, $2/10", " $4/10", "}'  | # print scaled columns 2 and 4
  sed '1s/^0 //'                        | # Remove leading "0 "
  tr -d '\n'                            ; # Remove all newlines
  echo " 0"                             # append trailing "0" and newline
```

Note that the seds are totally superfluous here (the first one would certainly be replaced with a pattern match on the first awk); the point is that you can very easily build up the sort of processing you desire by constructing simple tools to do each task and running them all together.